# Using Font Awesome 5.7 icons in Shiny apps

Tags: r, shiny, font-awesome

Shiny’s `icon()` function only supports Font Awesome 4.7 icons. [A full list of the icons supported by Shiny can be found here](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/).

Since then, [Font Awesome has been updated many times with new icons.](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery) How to use Font Awesome 5 icons in Shiny apps, or how to upgrade Font Awesome in Shiny to version 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding the following line to your `ui.r` file will expand Shiny support for Font Awesome 5.7.2 icons:

```
tags$style("@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css);"),
```

Afterwards, you can use the function `icon("icon-name")` in your Shiny web app. For example, you can use `icon("vote-yea")` to check if these new Font Awesome icons are working as intended.