# Add Uicons to Shiny from local file

Tags: html, r, shiny, tags, shinydashboard

Looking to add [uicons](https://www.flaticon.com/uicons/) to my Shiny app. I have downloaded the fonts after making an account, and moved the CSS and webfonts to the root directory of my `.R` file.(per instructions) Now I want to add one of the icons in my `infobox` in Shiny, I have a very simple example

[image]

[image]

I think I could use some sort of `shiny::tags` but not sure which one, or how. I used [This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64018032/using-font-awesome-5-7-icons-in-shiny-apps) to help guide me,

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        tags$i("@import url(/css/uicons-regular-rounded.css);"),
        icon("fi fi-rr-camera")
        ))

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Which gives me this

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: does tags$i(HTML("@import url(/css/uicons-regular-rounded.css);")) work?

Comment: No, but I found that when I do `tags$style` The UI text goes away, not sure if this is even supported or not that is why I am asking around.

Comment: I tried these tags: `tags$i(class = "fi fi-rr-camera")),
      tags$head(tags$link(href = 'filepath', rel = "stylesheet")))`  but I can't  make the icon appear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all folders including `svg` folder into `www` folder in root of your shiny app. Then you can import the icon with `tags$img(src='svg/fi-rr-camera.svg')`

To use it in info box, simply wrap it with `tags$i`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$img(src='svg/fi-rr-camera.svg', height='40', width='40')
    infoBox("info","info",icon = tags$i(tags$img(src='svg/fi-rr-camera.svg', height='40', width='40')))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @phago29 mentioned, uicons-regular-rounded.css need to be in a subdirectory inside the project directory (or simply the directory using `setwd()`).

```
 library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(includeCSS('www/uicons-regular-rounded.css'),
                  
                  tags$i(class = "fi fi-rr-camera")))


server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(includeCSS('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'),

        tags$i(class = "material-icons", "accessibility", style = "font-size: 6em;")))


server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```